# Compare ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub and session.Publickey()

Tags: go, ssh, ssh-keys

am building application similar to github where user can dump their public key on my server than can authenticate it. I wanted to added user specific data on runtime based on if key is registered or not with my application (basically check in key database).

I tried testing with hardcoded values:

```
key := "ssh-rsa AAAA"
b := []byte(key)
newAuthorizedKey, _, _, _, err := ssh.ParseAuthorizedKey(b)
if err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err)
}

authorizedKey := ssh.MarshalAuthorizedKey(newAuthorizedKey)
fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%s", authorizedKey))
```

But keys don't match with what we get in session.Publickey()
Is it something to do with algoritms..
I see session.Publickey - `ssh-ed25519` while one on my system in `ssh-rsa`
How can I make them compatible?

I am using https://github.com/gliderlabs/ssh

Any help is really appreciated !!

Comment: You can't make an ssh-ed25519 key "compatible" with ssh-rsa, they are different types of keys. `MarshalAuthorizedKey` is the inverse of `ParseAuthorizedKey`, so you are just getting back the same string you started with. These are both valid key types for ssh though, so what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I am planing to only support ssh-rsa algo while dumping it to server. But seems like I have to provide instruction while doing that to make use your ~/.ssh/config is using rsa only

Comment: while you may still commonly see them around, most users should be migrating away from `ssh-rsa` keys which have been deprecated for a couple years now.